# Not able to read a line containing ) (closing bracket) through a batch script

Tags: batch-file

My text file contains the following lines:

```
;    
; TEST (C)kary global parameters file    
;    
;===================================================================   
; Test servers list    
;===================================================================    
TC_SERVER_NAME test123   
TC_SERVER_TITLE Tc_test
```

I am using the following lines of code to read the lines and get the TC_SERVER_NAME line.

```
FOR /f tokens^=*^ eol^= %%C IN (%TEST_FILE%) do    
(    
    echo %%C | findstr /i "TC_SERVER_NAME" >nul:    
    if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (    
    echo %%C >> %OUTFILE%    
    )    
)
```

However, I get the following error while executing this code.

> "kary was unexpected at this time"

However, if I remove the ")" before kary from the text file, the script executes fine and I get the desired results.
So what is wrong with this ")" over here. Is it treating the ")" as some command here? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Note: In place of ) if I use any other special characters, it works fine. So there is something special with this ")" which is creating this issue.

Comment: If you use special characters, the code you showed here would fail, as the `echo %%C` expands the line and it fails in the new cmd context (created by the pipe). But not a closing bracket, as it's harmless in the context

Answer (score 2):

The code and sample you posted, isn't responsible for the error.
There are only two obviously bugs, the opening bracket must be on the same line as the `FOR/F` and the redirection to `>nul:` should be only `>nul`.

It doesn't output anything, but it doesn't result in an error message.

The if statement can't work, as the expansion of `%errorlevel%` is done when the complete block is parsed, not when it is executed.

Foxidrives solution should solve this.

Or you can try this

```
findstr /i "TC_SERVER_NAME" %TEST_FILE% > %OUTFILE%
```

Comment: Hi jeb..thanks for the reply. there are two points here : 1) The opening bracket is on the same line as FOR..I am using a subroutine to have that logic.. it is just for simplicity purpose that i posted the logic in the do block itself. 2) I replaced nul: with nul but still it has no effect. 3) My other concern is if there had been any syntactical issues then why is the script executing perfectly if Iremove the ")" from that line or use any other special characters instead of ")" over there.

Comment: It could be an issue with your subroutine or with the new command context. But the code you showed has no problems, please show code that really has the issue

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
FOR /f tokens^=*^ eol^= %%C IN (%TEST_FILE%) do (    
    echo %%C | findstr /i "TC_SERVER_NAME" >nul
    if "%errorlevel%"=="0" >> %OUTFILE% echo %%C
)
```

You probably want this though:

```
@echo off
set test_file=source.txt
set outfile=out.txt
FOR /f tokens^=*^ eol^= %%C IN (%TEST_FILE%) do (    
    echo %%C | findstr /i "TC_SERVER_NAME" >nul && >> %OUTFILE% echo %%C
)
```

Comment: Hi foxidrive, thanks for the reply but the variables have already been assigned the text files in the earlier part of the code which I have not mentioned (did not want to make the source code lengthy). i want to re-iterate that this code works fine without the bracket ")" in "TEST (C)kary global parameters file" i.e  something like "TEST (C kary global parameters file".

Comment: Did you try it?  It works fine here.  The second one just echos the target string.  As for your code, it wasn't ever going to work with the DO all alone on the line like that.  It needs the parenthesis after it on the same line.

Comment: Hi foxdrive, you are right..this code wont execute but it was just for simplicity purpose that i posted it that way.. the entire logic in the 'do ' block.. but actually.. I am using a subroutine to separate the logic.. my actual code goes like this 
    :FOR /f tokens^=*^ eol^= %%C IN (%PAR_FILE%) do call      :process_line_single %%C

:process_line_single
set /a line=line+1
echo Line %line% = %*


echo %* | findstr /i "TC_SERVER_NAME" >nul:
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
echo %* >> %OUTFILE%
set value=true
goto :EOF
)

Answer (score 0):

@jeb last solution is simpler and best, however I would like to introduce you `&&`, so your batch would be

```
FOR /f "tokens=* eol=" %%C IN (%TEST_FILE%) do echo %%C | findstr /i "TC_SERVER_NAME" >nul && echo %%C >> %OUTFILE%
```

However, this is very unsafe, as text may contain `(`, `<`, `&`, `|`, `"`, `>` characters, which will modify command behavior. Use @jeb solution, instead of `FOR` and everything else. Is safer and faster!

Comment: Yeah jeb really needs to be introduced to `&&` I assume. ;)

Answer (score 0):

it works with enabledelayedexpanson:
(I "hardcoded" the input- and output-file for testing)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /f "tokens=* eol=" %%C IN (t.t) do  (    
    echo %%C | findstr /i "TC_SERVER_NAME" >nul:    
    if "!errorlevel!"=="0" ( echo %%C >> o.o )  
)
```